# Pontryagin dual of the Cantor space

Tags: duality-theorems, cantor-set

I'm looking for some reference to understand why the Pontryagin dual of the Cantor space $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{0,1\}$ is $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{0,1\}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pontryagin duality is defined for topological groups.  What group structure are you putting on these spaces?

Comment: Product topology of the discrete topologies on $\{ 0,1\}$.